# Making multiple scripts loader with jQuery Deferred object, am I doing it right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I am working on a better version of `$.getScript` function which can:

- load multiple scripts at once
- cache already loaded scripts
- trigger a callback after all required scripts were loaded

You may suggest some libraries such as requirejs or LABjs but I think I could make a similar one by using jQuery Deferred object. Here is my attempt so far:

```
(function($) {
    'use strict';

    var cachedScriptPromises = {};

    $.require = function(url, callback, errback) {
        var urls = (url instanceof Array) ? url : [url],
            promises = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
            var url = urls[i];
            if ( ! cachedScriptPromises[url]) {
                cachedScriptPromises[url] = $.Deferred(function(defer) {
                    $.ajax({
                        dataType: 'script',
                        cache: true,
                        url: url
                    }).then(defer.resolve, defer.reject);
                }).promise();
            }
            promises.push(cachedScriptPromises[url]);
        }
        $.when.apply($, promises).done(callback).fail(errback);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

The idea is store one promise object for each script url then trigger the callback when all deferred objects were resolved.

<s>I don't know how to test this function correctly but please take a look at this test page, if you refresh the page several times, one of the output may be missed (occur more often on Chrome than Firefox).</s>

**Update** - Below is one of my test case that sometimes didn't log anything:

```
$.require(['jquery.log.js', 'foo.js'], function() {
    $('#log').log('jquery.log.js and foo.js were loaded!');
});
```

jquery.log.js:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.log = function(msg) {
        this.each(function() {
            $(this).append('<p>' + msg + '</p>');
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

foo.js:

```
$('#log').log('Foo!');
```

So is there any wrong with my `$.require` function?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [head.js](http://headjs.com/). I believe it has all the functionality you want.

Comment: Why tthe deferred anti pattern? just set cachedScriptPromises[url] to `$.ajax(...`, similarly, why the errback/callback? Why not return the $.when.apply ?

Comment: I forgot that `$.ajax` returns a promise. Using `$.Deferred` makes my code more complicated but I think I used it correctly. I changed `cachedScriptPromises[url] = $.ajax(...` like you said but the error seemed to occur more frequent than before. I will try to find a right way to check this instead of refreshing the test page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that jquery.log.js and foo.js would be loaded in parallel. If foo.js was loaded first, it would throw an error (log function is undefined). So I must put `$.require` on foo.js:

```
$.require('jquery.log.js').done(function() {
    $('#log').log('Foo!');
});
```

About the question am I doing it right with jQuery Deferred object, here are some changes that were suggested by @Benjamin Gruenbaum:

1. `$.ajax` returns a promise so don't need to wrap it inside a new deferred object.
2. Using promise object for better readable code so `$.require` function should return a promise instead of using callback/errback.

`$.require` function after the changes:

```
(function($) {
    'use strict';

    var cachedScriptPromises = {};

    $.require = function(url) {
        var urls = (url instanceof Array) ? url : [url],
            promises = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
            var url = urls[i];
            if ( ! cachedScriptPromises[url]) {
                cachedScriptPromises[url] = $.ajax({
                    dataType: 'script',
                    cache: true,
                    url: url
                });
            }
            promises.push(cachedScriptPromises[url]);
        }
        return $.when.apply($, promises);
    };
})(jQuery);
```